# How to get JSON format returned from flask directly in Vue

Tags: vue.js, flask, vuejs2

When a user uploads a file, I want to process it in Flask, and show the processed file back to the user.

When the image is uploaded from the front end, it is sent to Flask.

flask app.py:

```py
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    return jsonify(info_text=info_text, dst_url=dst_url, font_color=font_color, part_name=part_name,rate_part=rate_part,rate_adult=rate_adult,file_name=file_name)
```

Vue file:

```js
methods: {
  getMessage() {
    const path = 'http://127.0.0.1:4555/';
    axios.get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          this.msg = res.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(error);
        });
  },
},
created() {
  this.getMessage();
},
```

It does not accept the returned value.

Comment: I want to get the result as soon as the user uploads the image.

Comment: What do you mean in `It does not accept the returned value`? How are you displaying `msg` in your template?

Comment: It does not accept the returned value

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: It returns Jason from the flask but I can't get it from Vue.

Comment: If I have a return value processed by the server in vue, can I get it right away?

Comment: It should be returned in `res.data` in your code. What happens instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762051/there-is-no-change-to-the-frontpage-when-i-get-a-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `msg` in your `data` section to make it reactive.  Set it to `null`, and then update it async as you already do.